# Does anyone know about a web client for GIS from the Vaadin framework?

Tags: web-mapping, geocoding, framework

Reviewing the universe of GIS tools on the Web, I see that several customers have already developed GIS on the Web, so the is no need to start from scratch. Now I have come across the [Vaadin framework](https://vaadin.com/home) that appears appropriate for someone like me who does not have much experience with web technologies (html, javascript, css, etc.).

Could you tell me if there is any web client for GIS from the Vaadin framework?

Answer (score 1):

I clearly do not use the Vaadin framework (not a judgement, just a choice ;)).
For this reason, I didn't try but you can check the [OpenLayers 3 addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/openlayers-3-wrapper-for-vaadin) and the [V-Leaflet addon](https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/v-leaflet) (for Leaflet)

Both need Vaadin version 7 (7.2+ for OpenLayers 3)

Answer (score 0):

We use the Vaadin framework and it is a good solution to build big RIAs with a small developement team.
As we had other projects with Vaadin, and needed to migrate to Vaadin 7, it was actually me who initiated the vol3 (https://vaadin.com/directory#!addon/openlayers-3-wrapper-for-vaadin) project. It was outsourced to Vaadin Ltd.

We use OpenLayers3 with Vaadin 7 to 'GISify' our ERP system. It works great, it is stable and reliable. At the moment the project is lacking support, so development is a little limited, but 2 developers from Vaadin Ltd and I are trying to maintain the codebase and improve vol3 to make it better and up to date.

I hope this helps, but what was your question again? ;)